# Pulling text from list items using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: perl, xpath, www-mechanize

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li>Stuff 1</li>
    <li>Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I pull the text from the list items using [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox `xpath` function?](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Expath(_$query,_%25options_))

It seems like this should work, it's basically pulled from the documentation but it's coming up empty:

```
 my @text = $mech->xpath('//div[@class="chosen-drop"]/ul/li/text()');
```

I must be missing something with the xpath.

Comment: I suspect you are not showing your complete HTML document. There might be a namespace in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these files:

mech_xpath.pl:

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use Data::Dump qw/dump/;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get_local('local.html');

my @text = $mech->xpath('//div[@class="chosen-drop"]/ul/li/text()');
warn dump \@text;

<>;
```

local.html:

```
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li>Stuff 1</li>
    <li>Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Stuff 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Gives this output:

```
[
  bless({
    # tied MozRepl::RemoteObject::TiedHash
  }, "MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance"),
  bless({
    # tied MozRepl::RemoteObject::TiedHash
  }, "MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance"),
  bless({
    # tied MozRepl::RemoteObject::TiedHash
  }, "MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance"),
]
```

So everything looks to be working. How are you checking the contents of `@text`?

Comment: OK, there was some jquery on the page that was generating the list items. They were not there when I ran my script.